Trying to make my (app on an emulator) access data from my local API
Tech: .NET MAUI, Visual Studio, Android Emulator
I'm developping an Android App with MAUI.
The goal is to get a list of people from our local API and display it.
Simple isn't it?!
But, I'm face to a "Connection failure".
fyi: i'm doing my first internship, my coworkers don't know a thing about MAUI and I feel horrible not being able to do such an easy thing (i'm more a Spring/Angular/VM person).

In swagger, I can tell my API is working just fine.
http://localhost:5165/people gets me the Json of the list of people in the DB.
In the emulated environment, when I open a Google Chrome page and type the url:
http://10.0.2.2:5165/people
I get the json datas just right (I tried with another one that needed parameters, and great, it works!)
But, when it comes to getting these informations in my app, in the emulator, I get "Connection failure". Not much informations.
The url I'm telling my app to go to:
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://10.0.2.2:5165/people");
I event tried with the famous monkeyFinder app's Json, and everything worked nice.
Is there a port mistake here?

Android requires https urls unless specific exclusions are made
